# Hiding Interface Methods

Tags: java

In java is there a way to make a class implementing the interface methods to private?

Something like this:

```
class A implement interface1
{
   //make this private
   public void test()
   {
   }
}
```

Comment: No, you cannot. Methods in interfaces are by definition "public abstract".

Comment: ^ That and you cannot reduce the visibility of an overriden method.

Comment: Are you looking for something similar to this? http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue225.html

Comment: That would be saying "my class implements some of this interface" which defeats the purposes of interfaces all together. You could use delegation / inner classes etc ensure that only your code can call a method. If the exposed method is called it could throw an exception. But you can't really make it private.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**. You can't change the access modifier of a method you're implementing from an interface. Because, the resulting `Object` would no longer implement the interface.

Answer (score 0):

Methods in Interface are defined `public`.
It's cannot be `private`.